# Why does fabric resize my object when I move it?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am implementing snap to canvas edges on the object's scaling event.
In order to snap it to the left edge of the canvas, I have to set the left position to be equal to the canvas' left. I would also have to add to the width the amount I moved the object by.

The odd thing is, just from setting the new left position, sometimes my object shrinks/grows.

Is it because fabric is doing some kind of scaling under the hood? If I add the offset to my width to keep the object at the correct size, the odd behavior becomes more apparent.

```
threshold = 5;
_fabric.on('object:scaling', handleScaled);

function handleScaled(event) {
    const shape = event.target && event.target.shape;
    const shapeSize = shape.left + shape.width;
    const snapeAmnt = Math.abs(screenSize - shapeSize);
    if (Math.abs(screenSize - shapeSize) > threshold) {
        shape.width += snapeAmnt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post some sample code where issue can be reproduced

Comment: I added a snippet above. It pretty much increases/decreases the width when the fabric object is within my canvas by 5px; However, it doesn't look smooth. It kind of jumps to the edge a few times and I'm guessing this is because after I set the new width, the scale event goes back to the previous mouse position. And they fight and and fourth.